# Question about iOS WiFi that requires knowledge of system API and functionality to solve was deemed off-topic

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, scope, closed-questions

In December I posted this question: [iOS static IP Address and Wi-Fi icon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27662107/31326) which was finally put on hold yesterday as being off topic and belonging on Super User.

The basis for this judgment was that I was asking a network configuration question (DNS configuration in iOS) and not a programming related question.

My objection to this judgment was that in order to give an authoritative answer to my particular question, I needed a deep analysis of the behavior of an iOS subsystem (one called Reachability) under specific conditions (No DNS server on the network, but need  DNS server address to be configured).  Without such an understanding, any answer that solved my problem would be only be a "magical" solution that did what I needed without knowing why it actually worked<sup>1</sup>.

Obviously I failed in my attempts to convince the crowd that my point of view was the correct one.  However I am still convinced that SO is the place to ask this question, and that SU would have fewer of the people capable of answering the *why* of my question.

So while trying to not sound like I am simply ranting here, my Meta question comes down to wanting to know how to better partition a question between something like SO and SU.

1. Questions purely about code - sure, SO is the place
2. Questions about public configuration of a computer - sure, take it to SU
3. Questions like mine that straddle code and public configuration - SO or SU?
4. I am mistaken about my own question and I should have taken it straight to SU!

---

**Update 23 Feb 2015**

I debuted my original question on Ask Different a couple of weeks ago and eventually applied a bounty to try an get more interest.  Even though I have had nearly 100 views (yoo-hoo!) and managed to garner 1 up vote on the question, I still have had nada with regards with any sort of answer that solves my problem.

I am not surprised about this result - it was what I expected.  But it does seem to negate peoples insistence that that my question belonged on that site.

It seems that I should now shop my question around on Super User.

---

<sup>1</sup> I eventually did discover a DNS configuration that solved my problem, but I have no explanation as to *why* it solved it.

Comment: There is zero content in your question that is appropriate for SO. Zero. It's a network configuration/OS question, neither of which are proper for SO. SO is for programming (code) and programmers tools related questions, neither of which are any part of your question. When in doubt, read the guidelines in the [help], which describes the guidelines currently in place for each site. Your opinion regarding what knowledge someone needs in order to answer it is irrelevant; I can decide that any question about any computer topic requires in-depth knowledge of the code, but that doesn't make it so.

Comment: The fact that I need to know that my chair is made of oak in order to glue it up most effectively does not make my post about fixing it a forestry question. There do exist technically-competent end users, and programmers are also end users.

Answer (score 23):

Your question has *nothing* to do with code/programming as far as I can see (and I did read it all, and your answer). As you noted, no user code could fix your problem, nor did you provide any code (for obvious reasons).

Arguing that an answer requires knowledge of the iOS code base does not make it a programming question. To a certain extent, *every* computing question requires knowledge of the underlying code base (or at least what that code base does).

Given that it was specific to an iOS device, I would have actually asked it on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) instead of SO or SU.

To answer your question **directly**:

1. A question is about code: SO
2. A question is about a programming concept/language: SO/Programmers
3. A question is about *using* (configuration included) a computer: SU
4. A question is about *using* an iOS device: Ask Different

Your question involves no code at all (no straddling either) it easily fits into categories 3 and 4, and since you need an iOS expert, I would go with 4.

Comment: Suppose I ask my specific question on SU or AD (and yes, I did consider where to ask before putting it on SO), from my POV anyone there can only say "yes, this value solves your problem, but I don't know why".  How do I get to the "why" when I am looking for a solution that points to somewhere in the Apple programming docs that explains how their reachability code behaves?  Nothing on AD comes close to my situation (and yes I did look)

Comment: @PeterM Asking "why" a program (as a black box) does *anything* is off-topic for any SE site, as the answer will be "because it does". Assuming that source is publicly available (doubt it, its Apple), someone could potentially point you to it, but thats about it. I could *maybe* see a seriously reworded question that is looking for the code relating to this flying, but your specific question is not that.

Comment: I see the `why` as being very important, as without understanding I cannot guarantee that such an answer will work in all cases.  This particular type network configuration (no DNS server, self contained network) is actually pretty common in industrial control networks so knowing how to properly configure a device is kinda critical.  Not knowing why means having to guess the configuration.

Comment: @PeterM Sure, but none of that requires code, or knowledge of code. Just enough knowledge about how iOS implemented (in terms of features) their DNS configuration settings to cover all the cases. Certainly that knowledge can be *derived* from code, but its still not a programming question. As I said previously, "Show me the code that handles X" could be a *on-topic* (albeit poor) question here.

Comment: @PeterM Furthermore, if there was say, a user manual that documented all this, such documentation would not be programmatic in nature, and so it would *still* be a better fit for Ask Different where the experts would know about and could provide said documentation.

Comment: I never said I wanted code, what I wanted was technical references that could only be supplied by people who deal with iOS code on a daily basis.   That way I can see the boundaries of Apples magic and not unexpectedly trip over the edge of it

Comment: As @Kevin noted, the most an iOS developer could provide would be an API doc (not likely to solve your problem). A user manual would not be in the purview of SO as I noted right before you posted. One thing to potentially clear up, just because an expert here is likely to have the knowledge you want doesn't make the question on-topic. I could answer a bunch of stuff about Outlook after writing some add-ins for it, but that doesn't make any Outlook config questions on-topic here. Of course, questions on how to *program* Outlook add-ins are.

Comment: And that is the conundrum that I am trying to solve with my question here.   IMHO the experts who could answer my question are on SO, but because there is no code per se, the question is deemed to be off topic for SO.  However *I* doubt that there are experts on AD or SU who have the internal knowledge and experience of iOS operations in order to answer the technical aspects of *why* any solution works so thus can't really answer my actual question.  (And I say that latter part as I took a look at AD and there are no technical questions about DNS and iOS).  So I am screwed either way.

Comment: @PeterM You aren't necessarily screwed either way. By asking on AD, you get the *experiential* answers (I had the same problem and fixed it X way) *and* you get any iOS developers who also use that site who may or may not know the answer. Many SO users do actively participate on the other, more specific sites for their expertise.

Comment: Well as per the voting, I'm already screwed on SO.  I will give you that I am probably underestimating the AD users.  However I want to want to follow up with this on Kevin's answer.   But I think that this discussion has probably run its course for now.  I'm going to post on AD (as long as I don't violate a multiple posting guideline) what I posted on SO, and see what happens.  If its also a blood bath there I'm not going to be too happy :D

Comment: @PeterM I already looked at their on-topic page and didn't see any giant red-flags. You *should* be ok.

Answer (score 13):

> My objection to this judgment was that IMHO in order to give an authoritative answer to my particular question I needed a deep analysis of the behavior of an iOS subsystem (reachability) under specific conditions (No DNS server on the network, but need DNS server address to be configured).

This still has nothing to do with *programming*, unless you're an Apple engineer and you're asking us how to make iOS do the right thing (which is not what you were asking).  Thus, it is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: But without a technical based explanation derived from the operation of the library functions, any answer is purely `magical`.  I do not like to have `magical` answers.

Comment: @PeterM Whats wrong with `magic`? I love magic, until it stops working. Then I get angry and write my own magic :) Seriously, since writing your own really isn't an option, learning how to use/get around the magic is what you need, which isn't what SO is for (not for system config issues anyways).

Comment: @PeterM: AFAIK iOS is closed source.  The most we could possibly do is Google up the relevant API docs for you.

Comment: @Kevin Pointing to the official iOS docs is something that is done in innumerable SO questions.  I do not know the iOS API docs backwards, so it is quite possible that I have missed the relevant information.

Comment: @PeterM: Perhaps, but most of those iOS questions begin with "I'm calling the `foo()` function and..." rather than "My WiFi icon is missing and...".

Comment: @PeterM Additionally, documentation should almost never *be* the answer, it should just back it up.  In C# we link to MSDN all the time, but thats just to say "Here's the official stuff related to what I'm saying".

Comment: OK so I reword my SO question to be .. "My program can't access anything on the local network .. here is the network code..".  The presented code is valid, working network code.  Eventually through a series of questions, it is finally realized that the there is no network reachability (as deemed by the Apple framework, even though there is an actual wi-fi network that can be pinged). How is that solved? Does my question suddenly become off topic?  Because I could have posted a question like that.

Comment: @PeterM: In that case, the top-voted answer would probably be something like "Your program is working correctly.  Go fix your iOS config."  It would not go into further detail about how to fix the config.

Comment: @PeterM Yes, it would become off-topic because the problem switches from a programming issue ("My code doesn't work") to a system config one ("How do I connect to a network").

Comment: OK so now I go to AD (which I am actually going to do) and say "my network code is fine, I can ping other devices on my network, but the Apple reachability API says that I there is no network connection.  How do I fixe this, given that it is a standalone network with no DNS?".  I am betting that the people on AD will say WTF are you talking about (although Bradely thinks different) and I am going to have a similar discussion on AD as I had in my SO question where I was trying to explain why there is a difference between actual network connectivity and Apple's idea of what connectivity is.

Comment: @PeterM: Have you tried *asking* on AD?  Keep in mind, they and Ask Ubuntu both regularly deal with Unix stuff.  They're not idiots.

Comment: I'm about to ask there.  But if it crashes and burns there I will be coming after both of you .. lol   When the results are in I am going to update this Meta question

Comment: @PeterM Note that unless you are actually writing code (sounds like you aren't), their API hasn't said *anything* to you, their GUI has. Chances are decent (without any actual knowledge) that the "WiFi Icon" functionality is all internal and there *is* no API for it.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET You just had too say one more thing!  The crux of my SO question is that iOS internally determines for you if there is network connectivity.  A good iOS app believes what the iOS API system tells you about the network.  But what the iOS API says is not necessarily the truth (as in *my* case) and you have to twist the devices configuration in order to get the iOS API to admit that there is a network connection - so that your well formed iOS app can communicate.  The WiFi icon is indicative of what the iOS API believes.

Comment: @PeterM Thats important information! Granted, its still likely more in scope for AD, since your question isn't about the API itself but why its feeding you a specific value in a specific situation and how to configure the system in such a way to change that. Still, it lends some programming context to it that would have helped your SO question fare a bit better, especially if you indicated what code you used to determine connectivity, etc.